# Multiple instances of mobile applications

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I have a small application based on react-native.
It uses Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for notification functionality.
Now I have a task to publish the application in the Play Market and App Store using 14 app IDs (for localization and store optimization).
For example:

```
company-dashboard-app
company-dashboard-peluqueria
company-dashboard-per-parrucchieri
company-kassensystem-friseur-dashboard
company-logiciel-coiffure
```

and etc
Do I really need to create 14 instances of react-native and firebase or is there an easier way?
Maintaining 14 instances of applications is a big pain.